# What is meant exactly by "eigenstate ensemble average"?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, quantum-information, many-body, quantum-statistics

I am currently reading about Eigenstate Thermalization Hypothesis (ETH) and Berry's conjecture. In the [paper by Srednicki](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9403051) on chaos and quantum thermalization, in Eq.(3.8) he calculates the average of a quantity in eigenstate ensemble (EE):
$$
\langle\Phi_{\alpha\alpha}(p_{~\!_1})\rangle_{\!_{EE}} \equiv \left\langle \int d^3p_{~\!_2}\cdots d^3p_{~\!_N} |\psi_\alpha(p)|^2\right\rangle_{EE}
$$
Here $p_i$ are the 3-momentum of the $i$-th particle, $\psi_\alpha(p)$ are energy eigenstates in the momentum basis, and $p\equiv p_{~\!_1},\cdots,p_{~\!_N}$.

He then goes on to state that

> The subscript EE stands for “eigenstate ensemble.” This is a fictitious ensemble which describes the properties of a typical energy eigenfunction. Individual
> eigenfunctions behave as if they were selected at random from the eigenstate ensemble.
> Berry’s conjecture also asserts that the eigenstate ensemble is gaussian...

My question is what exactly is meant by eigenstate ensemble average? According to the quoted text, it means that we take an average over all eigenstates each drawn randomly with a gaussian weight. But if that is true, the RHS of Eq.(3.8) of the paper should be independent of the index $\alpha$, since we just averaged over $\psi_\alpha$, which is not the case. So, what exactly does it mean?

Comment: It is considering an ensemble as described on page 7: 
" Now return to the thought experiment in which the system is repeatedly prepared in the same initial state (specified by the Cα’s), and the momentum of one atom is repeatedly measured after the same elapsed time "

So an ensemble of all the SAME state. On each instance of the ensemble you take a measurement of p1 and construct a probability distribution of p1.